# D3 Multi-Colored Bars In a Floating Bar Chart Determined By Time Calculation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

Current:

[image]

Desired:

[image]

The following bar graph consists of two horizontal bars.  One of them represents the time span for which an employee was scheduled to work for the day. The second represents the time that the employee actually worked. The second bar is fractured into 3 separate sections based on the data (work_start_1-work_end_1/a gap where the employee took a break/work_start_2-work_end_2). The employee happened to work longer than they were scheduled. How do I make the corresponding area on the second bar (worked) red as to alert that the employee has worked too long? This is proving difficult with D3.

```
<script src="moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>

var all_moments = [];

var scheduled_start = moment("2015-03-25 08:00:00");
var scheduled_end = moment("2015-03-25 17:00:00");

var worked_start_1 =  moment("2015-03-25 08:00:00");
var worked_end_1 =  moment("2015-03-25 12:00:00");

var worked_start_2 =  moment("2015-03-25 13:00:00");
var worked_end_2 =  moment("2015-03-25 19:00:00");

all_moments.push(scheduled_start);
all_moments.push(scheduled_end);
all_moments.push(worked_start_1);
all_moments.push(worked_end_1);
all_moments.push(worked_start_2);
all_moments.push(worked_end_2);

var earliest_moment = moment.min(all_moments);
var latest_moment = moment.min(all_moments);


var data=[
    {"action": "Scheduled", "tooltipTitle": "Scheduled","gap": false,"to": scheduled_end,"from": scheduled_start},
    {"action": "Worked", "tooltipTitle": "Worked", "gap": false,"to": worked_end_1,"from": worked_start_1},
    {"action": "Worked", "tooltipTitle": "Gap", "gap": true, "to": worked_start_2,"from": worked_end_1},
    {"action": "Worked", "tooltipTitle": "Worked", "gap": false, "to": worked_end_2,"from": worked_start_2}
]

var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 100},
              width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
              height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var y = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, height], .08);

var x = d3.time.scale()
        .domain([earliest_moment,latest_moment])
        .range([0,width]);

y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.action; }));
x.domain([d3.min(data,function(d){return d.from;}), d3.max(data,function(d){return d.to;})]);

var customTimeFormat = d3.time.format("%I:%M:%p");  

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom")
            .ticks(10)
            .tickFormat(customTimeFormat);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .style("font", "14px times")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", width-75)
    .attr("dx", ".71em")
    .attr("dy", "-.71em");
    //.text("Temperatures (C)");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .style("font", "18px times")
    .style('font-family', '"Open Sans", sans-serif')
    .call(yAxis);


svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.action); })
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.from); })
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.to)-x(d.from) })
    .style("fill", function(d,i) {
        if(d.action == "Worked" && d.gap == false) {
            return d3.rgb("#76ff03");
        }
        else if(d.action == "Worked" && d.gap == true) {
            return d3.rgb("#e0e0e0");
        }
        else {
            return d3.rgb("#00e5ff");
        }
    });


var tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append('div')
    .attr('class', 'tooltip');

tooltip.append('div')
    .attr('class', 'tooltipTitle');
    tooltip.append('div')
    .attr('class', 'timeRange');

svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .on('mouseover', function(d) {
        //console.log(m1.format("MMM Do YY"));

        tooltip.select('.tooltipTitle').html("<b>" + d.tooltipTitle + "</b>");
        tooltip.select('.timeRange').html( d.from.format("LT") + " to " + d.to.format("LT"));

        tooltip.style('display', 'block');
        tooltip.style('opacity',2);
    })
    .on('mousemove', function(d) {
        tooltip.style('top', (d3.event.layerY + 10) + 'px')
        .style('left', (d3.event.layerX - 25) + 'px');
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
        tooltip.style('display', 'none');
        tooltip.style('opacity',0);
    });
```

How do I make the corresponding area on the second bar (worked) red as to alert that the employee has worked too long?

Comment: How do I make the corresponding area on the second bar (worked) red as to alert that the employee has worked too long?

Comment: Convert your data so it can be used in a **Stacked Bar Chart** using `d3.stack()`   https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using linear gradients, where you set the stops based on the width of the schedules times, and then apply the fill to the actual worked time bars

The gradient is set up with a stop using the 'to' value from the first object in the array, assuming that this will always be your 'scheduled' time. The gradient uses userSpaceOnUse so that uses the coordiates from the SVG container, rather than each rect it is applied to.

```
let gradient = svg.append("defs")
   .append("linearGradient")
   .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
   .attr("id", "gradient")
   .attr("x1", 0)
   .attr("y1", 0)
   .attr("x2", width)
   .attr("y2", 0);

let offset = x(data[0].to) / width

gradient.append('stop').attr("offset", 0).attr("stop-color", 'green')
gradient.append('stop').attr("offset", offset).attr("stop-color", 'green')
gradient.append('stop').attr("offset", offset).attr("stop-color", 'red')
gradient.append('stop').attr("offset", 1).attr("stop-color", 'red')
```

Then the gradient is applied as the fill on the rects:

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
.data(data)
.enter().append("rect")
.attr("class", "bar")
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.action); })
.attr("height", y.rangeBand())
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.from); })
.attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.to)-x(d.from) })
.style("fill", function(d,i) {

if(d.action == "Worked" && d.gap == false) {
return 'url(#gradient)';
}
else if(d.action == "Worked" && d.gap == true) {
return d3.rgb("#e0e0e0");
}
else {
return d3.rgb("#00e5ff");
}
```

```js
var all_moments = [];

var scheduled_start = moment("2015-03-25 08:00:00");
var scheduled_end = moment("2015-03-25 17:00:00");

var worked_start_1 =  moment("2015-03-25 08:00:00");
var worked_end_1 =  moment("2015-03-25 12:00:00");

var worked_start_2 =  moment("2015-03-25 13:00:00");
var worked_end_2 =  moment("2015-03-25 19:00:00");


all_moments.push(scheduled_start);
all_moments.push(scheduled_end);
all_moments.push(worked_start_1);
all_moments.push(worked_end_1);
all_moments.push(worked_start_2);
all_moments.push(worked_end_2);

var earliest_moment = moment.min(all_moments);
var latest_moment = moment.min(all_moments);


var data=[
{"action": "Scheduled", "tooltipTitle": "Scheduled","gap": false,"to": scheduled_end,"from": scheduled_start},
{"action": "Worked", "tooltipTitle": "Worked", "gap": false,"to": worked_end_1,"from": worked_start_1},
{"action": "Worked", "tooltipTitle": "Gap", "gap": true, "to": worked_start_2,"from": worked_end_1},
{"action": "Worked", "tooltipTitle": "Worked", "gap": false, "to": worked_end_2,"from": worked_start_2}
]

var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 100},
width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
.rangeRoundBands([0, height], .08);

var x = d3.time.scale()
.domain([earliest_moment,latest_moment])
.range([0,width]);

y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.action; }));
x.domain([d3.min(data,function(d){return d.from;}), d3.max(data,function(d){return d.to;})]);

var customTimeFormat = d3.time.format("%I:%M:%p");  

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom")
.ticks(10)
.tickFormat(customTimeFormat);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)

svg.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
  
let gradient = svg.append("defs")
   .append("linearGradient")
 .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
   .attr("id", "gradient")
   .attr("x1", 0)
   .attr("y1", 0)
   .attr("x2", width)
   .attr("y2", 0);

let offset = x(data[0].to) / width
  
gradient.append('stop').attr("offset", 0).attr("stop-color", 'green')
gradient.append('stop').attr("offset", offset).attr("stop-color", 'green')
gradient.append('stop').attr("offset", offset).attr("stop-color", 'red')
gradient.append('stop').attr("offset", 1).attr("stop-color", 'red')



svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.style("font", "14px times")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(xAxis)
.append("text")
.attr("x", width-75)
.attr("dx", ".71em")
.attr("dy", "-.71em");
//.text("Temperatures (C)");

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.style("font", "18px times")
.style('font-family', '"Open Sans", sans-serif')
.call(yAxis);


svg.selectAll(".bar")
.data(data)
.enter().append("rect")
.attr("class", "bar")
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.action); })
.attr("height", y.rangeBand())
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.from); })
.attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.to)-x(d.from) })
.style("fill", function(d,i) {

if(d.action == "Worked" && d.gap == false) {
return 'url(#gradient)';
}
else if(d.action == "Worked" && d.gap == true) {
return d3.rgb("#e0e0e0");
}
else {
return d3.rgb("#00e5ff");

}


});


var tooltip = d3.select("body")
.append('div')
.attr('class', 'tooltip');

tooltip.append('div')
.attr('class', 'tooltipTitle');
tooltip.append('div')
.attr('class', 'timeRange');

svg.selectAll(".bar")
.on('mouseover', function(d) {

//console.log(m1.format("MMM Do YY"));

tooltip.select('.tooltipTitle').html("<b>" + d.tooltipTitle + "</b>");
tooltip.select('.timeRange').html( d.from.format("LT") + " to " + d.to.format("LT"));

tooltip.style('display', 'block');
tooltip.style('opacity',2);

})
.on('mousemove', function(d) {
tooltip.style('top', (d3.event.layerY + 10) + 'px')
.style('left', (d3.event.layerX - 25) + 'px');
})
.on('mouseout', function() {
tooltip.style('display', 'none');
tooltip.style('opacity',0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great answer. Thank you very much!